# Firebird don't show duplicate rows by column

Tags: sql, select, firebird

I have a table that contains the following data:

```
- DATEURM     IDV    UNID
- 2013-02-02  15259  W0L0TGF0572 
- 2013-02-02  15259  W0L0TGF0572
- 2013-02-02  15674  ZFA18503158 
- 2013-02-02  16157  ZFA18503158
- 2013-02-02  16157  ZFA18503158
- ...
```

and i use this query to select data from it:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL order_date WHERE DATEURM BETWEEN DATE 'today'+10 AND DATE 'today'+40 order by DATEURM asc ROWS 50
```

What I would like is to not get duplicate rows of the UNID column and the result be something like:

```
- DATEURM  IDV UNID
- 2013-02-02  15259  W0L0TGF0572 
- 2013-02-02  16157  ZFA18503158
- ...
```

I played around with DISTINCT and GROUP BY but didn't manage to get any good result after a few hours :(

Comment: what you get if you add DISTINCT to the select clause?

Comment: If i add a simple DISTINCT to the to the select clause for that table i only get the UNID column in the output. I presume i also need some sort of COUNT or SUM to make it work.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14474634/255257)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you say now you want one row per unid and you don't mind which other values you get, so try this:

```
SELECT unid, min(dateurm) dateurm, min(idv) idv 
  FROM order_date
 WHERE DATEURM BETWEEN current_date + 10 AND current_date + 40
 group by unid
 order by 2
```

over the same data I get:

```
UNID        DATEURM             IDV
=========== ========== ============ 
W0L0TGF0572 2013-02-02        15259
ZFA18503158 2013-02-02        15674

SQL>
```

Comment: The issue that i have with this is that the last 2 results are still not unique from the UNID column point of view, i would like only one row per UNID with any of the values for the IDV (IDV sort of point to the same data but i still need at least one of the IDV to get there).

Comment: You don't state that in your question, you shall edit it to add that vital information!

Comment: This indeed works perfect (although without the comma after idv), thank you for your time and help.